# Data structure used to perform the union operation on two disjoint sets

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, union

What basic data structure  would be best to use for the union operation on two disjoint sets?

Are there any algorithms that would run in O(1) time?

I'm thinking some variety of Hash Table, but I'm kind of stuck.
This is for a study guide in Algorithms and Data Structures.

The full question:
The set operation UNION takes two disjoint sets S1 and S2 as input, and returns a
set S = S1 ∪ S2 consisting of all the elements of S1 and S2 (the sets S1 and S2 are
usually destroyed by this operation). Explain how you can support UNION operation
in O(1) time using a suitable data structure. Discuss what data structure you would
use and describe the algorithm for the UNION operation.

Comment: "best" in which regard? What are the other operations required? Just supporting union can easily done in O(1).

Comment: You need to say what other operations the sets are supposed to support.  There is no constant time union, for example, for sets that are supposed to implement java.util.Set.  If someone is wants constant time union, they are usually directing you toward union-find algorithms (google it), but that is very different from implementing a normal Set interface.

Answer (score 1):

If the sets are disjoint, a linked list (with a head and tail) will be enough. The union in this case is only a concatenation of the lists. In C++:

```
struct LL {
    Value *val;
    LL *next;
};
struct LList{
    LL *head;
    LL *tail;
};
```

and the union operation will be:

```
void unify(LList* list1, LList* list2) {
    // assuming you take care of edge cases
    list1->tail->next = list2->head;
    list1->tail = list2->tail;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An interesting technique that sometimes applies to that problem (not always though, as you will see), is to use an array of "cycles", each cycle storing a set. The cycles are stored as a bunch of "next element" links, so `next[i]` will give an integer that represents the next item. In the end the links loop back, so the sets are necessarily disjoint.

The nice thing there is that you can union two sets together by swapping two items. If you have indexes `s1` and `s2`, then the sets they are in (`s1` and `s2` are not special representatives, you can refer to a set by any of its elements) can be unioned by swapping those positions:

```
int temp = next[s1];
next[s1] = next[s2];
next[s2] = temp;
```

Or however you can swap in your language. Java doesn't have a nice equivalent of `std::swap(&next[s1], &next[s2])` as far as I know.

This is obviously related to cyclic linked lists, but more compact. The downside is that you have to prepare your "universe" in advance. With linked lists you can arbitrarily add items. Also if your items are not the integers 0 to n then you will have an array on the side to do the mapping, but that's not really a pure downside or upside, it depends on what you need to do with it.

A bonus upside is that because you can refer to an item by index, it goes together more easily with other data structures, for example it likes to cooperate with the Union Find structure (which is also an array of integers, well two of them), inheriting the O(1) Union that both structure offer, keeping the amortized O(α(n)) Find of Union Find, and also (from the cycles structure) keeping the O(m) set enumeration for a set of size m. So you mostly get the best of both worlds.

In case it wasn't obvious, you can initialize the "universe" with "all singletons" like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < next.length; i++)
    next[i] = i;
```

The same as in Union Find.